# Multiple select statements in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm learning to write stored procedures. I want to have three select statements to my mysql stored procedure. 
Second and third select statements requires the result of their upper select statement.
I tried to write as follows. But not succeeded.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SPTeam`(IN date_x date, OUT   emplist3 varchar(200))

BEGIN
SELECT
(
   select emp_event.employee_id as emplist1
   from emp_event
   where emp_event.date = date_x
), 
(
   select emp_position.employee_id as emplist2
   from emp_position
   where FIND_IN_SET(emp_position.employee_id, emplist1)=0
   AND emp_position.position = "Cameraman"
),
(
   select employee.name as emplist3
   from employee
   where employee.id IN (emplist2)
);
END
```

This is the error I got.

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'emplist1' in 'where clause'
```

Someone Please correct me.
Thank U.

Comment: *But not succeeded.* means what? Exception?

Comment: You cant do such thing, you need to repeat second query in IN statement in third to get employee IDs

Comment: Another thing is that you cant obtain multiple rows in subquery when subselecting field

Comment: @Forward I edited the question with the error I got. Please check it.

Comment: @cichy  Isn't there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could store each of the select results in variables and then do a select on these variables:

```
DECLARE @emp_event as int
DECLARE @emp_position as int
DECLARE @emp_employeeName as int

SET @emp_event = (select emp_event.employee_id from emp_event where emp_event.date = date_x)
SET @emp_position = (select emp_position.employee_id from emp_position where FIND_IN_SET(emp_position.employee_id, @emp_event)=0 AND emp_position.position = "Cameraman")
SET @emp_employeeName = (select employee.name from employee where employee.id IN (@emp_position))

SELECT @emp_event as emplist1, @emp_position as emplist2, @emp_employeeName as emplist3
```

Comment: You can't select multiple rows into single variable

Answer (score 0):

If i understeand correctly what you need, it would be something like this:

```
   select employee.name as emplist3
   from employee
   where employee.id IN (
      select emp_position.employee_id
      from emp_position
      where emp_position.employee_id IN (
         select emp_event.employee_id
         from emp_event
         where emp_event.date = date_x
      )
      AND emp_position.position = "Cameraman"
   )
```